# Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition survey/literature review

Tags: reference-request, literature-research, dantzig-wolfe-decomposition

I was trying to find a literature review on Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition but was unable to do so. I found one on Benders, and another on Column-generation.

EDIT: If there is none, is there a paper that tends to be used as a representative of the algorithm? The more recent, the better, I would like to avoid using the original 1960 paper.

Comment: Not a literature review, but maybe this paper could be useful for you: https://www.ise.ncsu.edu/fuzzy-neural/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2018/08/decomposition-A-generic-view-of-Danzig-Wolfe-decomposition-in-mixed-iteger-programming.pdf